# Shell script to detemine OS version and restart a service

Tags: shell-script

I need to restart a service in multiple servers with different OS versions:

- Linux:

  - RHEL 5 to 8,
  - CentOS 5 to 8
  - SuSE 11, 12,
  - Oracle Linux 5 to 8
- AIX 7,
- HPUX 11.31

Can anyone help me here with a shell script which will determine the OS versions and will restart the service using service  restart or systemctl restart  or /sbin/init.d/ restart, etc. commands according to the OS versions.

Comment: The HPUX falls out of that list a bit. Is it just Linux distros and HPUX, or is your "etc." hiding other operating systems?

Comment: Hello Marcus, We have RHEL 5 to 8, SUSE 11-12, CentOS 5 to 7, AIX 7, Oracle Linux 5 to 8, HPUX 11.31 Operating systems in our environment and we need to restart a service at a particular time. So, would require help in preparing a script that will determine the OS and its version and restart the service.

Answer (score 2):

Ansible's built-in [`service` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_module.html) can restart services on a range of different init systems, which to the best of my knowledge cover all your listed operating systems.

So you don't need to write any other program, you just need to do the ansible tutorial (Which is not a bad place to start if you want to administrate multiple servers at once and saves you from a lot of work and inconsistencies), and then have

```yaml
- name: Restart service, in all cases
  ansible.builtin.service:
    name: YOURSERVICEHERE
    state: restarted
```

in your playbook.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I would surely try to built an ansible script but on the other hand, it would be of great help if a shell script can be provided as well

Comment: ansible executes a shell script. You can just check that.

Comment: I want to know how I can determine the OS and its versions as well with if clause. Any help would be appreciated.